# How to use JQUERY to select a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I intend to write a piece of code to select one option in a radio button. I used the following code which is saw being used to select a dropdown. I modified it and used it but its not working. Could you please point out my error?

```
$("div.classradio radio").val("Male");
```

this is the code I used but it doesn't work.

Comment: How would you do it "in HTML"? Remember that (or go find out), and you will know what to do in your script as well.

Answer (score 1):

`$("div.classradio radio").prop("checked", true)`

For versions of jQuery prior to 1.6, use:

`$("div.classradio radio").attr('checked', 'checked');`

Answer (score 0):

Why you want do this with jQuery? It's very simple with HTML:

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>
```

With jQuery you can do it like this:

`$('input:radio[name=gender]')[1].checked = true;`

The Number in the brackets indicates the radio button. Attention: jQuery starts counting at 0.

Comment: The value of the radio button is going to be sourced from a database so it change.. e.g. It can be male or female that's why I'm using the Jquery. I hope you understand

Comment: Why you dont want do to it with php?

Comment: I know I can, I just wanted to try it with Jquery. I'm learning it

Comment: It would be not very useful to do it with jQuery, what if the visitor of your website has disabled JavaScript? If you still want to do this with jQuery you should write the value from php into a hidden field and then read this value with jQuery and check the specified radio buton.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.classradio radio").val("Male")
```

This code mean find the element with tag  which is child of the div with class "classradio"

```
<div class="classradio">
    <radio></radio>       
</div>
```

Comment: ok. Thanks a lot for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the attribute of the input element by selector

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#FeMale').attr('checked',true);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" id="Male"/>Male
        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="FeMale" id="FeMale"/>Female
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```